# Receive Collection/Iterable as arguments in spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and I want to write a controller which will take `Collection`/`Iterable` as arguments. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "friends", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Callable<Iterable<User>> 
getFriendsOfUser(@RequestParam(required = true, name = "mobiles") Iterable<String> mobs) {
    // return callable
}
```

There is no compilation error, but I cannot make it work. Can you say how will this work? And how shall be the request to this api be constructed?

Comment: could you please post your RestURL?So that we can find out the issue.

Comment: I am using localhost for now, just like "http://localhost:8080/users/friends"

Comment: I don't see any request parameter in your URL then why are using requestParam?If it is a form element use Modelattribute or if it is a json use RequestParam

Comment: Ok, so can you help me to take a collection as the argument? should I make a model like
`public class Friend{ 
    private Collection<User> users;
//getters setters
}`

and then use @ModelAttribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String getFriendsOfUser(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "mobiles")  String[] mobiless){
....
}
```

and your mobile should be

```
mobiles=myValue1&mobiles=myValue2&mobiles=myValue3
```

or

```
mobiles=myvalue1,myValue2,myValue3
```

still if you have any doubt post your front-end code and Ajax call.

Comment: This is a GET request, but I want it as a POST. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can also use this for post call.Please post your front-end code so that we can give precise solution otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: I have not done any front end, this will be used as an api for android application, I am just trying out the api from a rest client.
Your solution works.
Correct me if I am wrong, Iterable cannot be sent as arguments for a POST request. Only arrays can be sent over api.

Comment: It can be. When you do a `POST` call with the following body: `["foo", "bar"]` then Spring will autobox it to a `Collection<String>` or to an `Iterable<String>`

Comment: @Debanjan Yes we can sent follow rorschach approach or if you want more precise answer let me know i will share.Kindly accept the answer if it works.

Comment: in that case do I have to take the input as a RequestBody?  @VelNaga it will be very helpful if you do so.

Comment: @Debanjan We can send Iterable using RequestBody.Jackson will convert that iterable into a Json Array.Just share your sample request i will share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've mapped a `POST` method so you might need `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`

`@RequestParam` is, as the name implies, for request parameters: `[host]/endpoint?param=foo&secondParam=bar`

whereas

`@RequestBody` is for JSON/XML or any other type content sent as the request's body.

Comment: Ok, so can you give an example to send a list/collection/iterable in a requestbody? Say, in this case, if I replace RequestParam with RequestBody, what should be the request body that I have to send to the server?

Comment: That's not true at all. If you are `POST`ing with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then `@RequestParam`s are appropriate, as the post body would look like a `GET` url after the `?`